# How to factorized this 4th degree polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I need your help to this polynomial's factorization.

Factorize this polynomials which doesn't have roots in Q.

$ \ f(x) = x^4 +2x^3-8x^2-6x-1 $

P.S.) Are there any generalized method finding 4<sup>th</sup> degree polynomials factor?

Comment: Turns out the roots are [not that bad](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E4+%2B2x%5E3-8x%5E2-6x-1+%3D+0), but I have no idea how one might tell just by looking at the polynomial.

Comment: By looking at the polynomial, if you cannot find the integer root, it means that the 4th degree polynomial is a product of two second degree polynomials. Therefore, try by letting $f(x)=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$, where $b=1, d=-1$

Comment: The polynomial is *not* irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Yes. So  I edited my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean about being irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ - it may have no roots over $\mathbb Q$, which is a different thing.

The general process for finding the roots of a quartic starts by trying to express it as a difference of two squares, and solving a cubic for the parameter involved (you can pair the four roots of the quartic in three different ways, which represent three different factorisations into two quadratics).

Often trying to spot a difference of two squares is a good method with quartics anyway, if you are stuck.

> Here I spotted $x^4+2x^3+x^2-9x^2-6x-1$ as a possible way forward - and this leads to a factorisation into quadratics with integer coefficients.

Comment: The hint that express as two squares was a big help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can always find the roots of a fourth degree polynomial. [The formulas are not pretty, but they do exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Using the formulas, or, like me, using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots%20of%20x%5E4%2B2x%5E3%E2%88%928x%5E2%E2%88%926x%E2%88%921), can show you that the roots of the polynomial are $1\pm\sqrt{2}$ and $-2\pm \sqrt{3}$ so the polynomial is

$$\begin{align}f(x)&=(x-1-\sqrt{2})(x-1+\sqrt{2})(x+2-\sqrt{3})(x+2+\sqrt{3})\\&=(x^2-2x-1)(x^2+4x+1)\end{align}$$

Comment: +1 and just corrected the typo in the second bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a general method for determining whether or not a [quartic is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic#Factoring_quartic_polynomials):

1. Does it have rational roots? In your case, the answer is negative, by the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).
2. Consider the polynomial $q(x)=p\left(x-\frac12\right)=x^4-\frac{19 x^2}2+3x-\frac3{16}$.
3. Consider the [resolvent cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic#Third_definition) of $q(x)$:\begin{align}r(x)&=x^3+2\times\left(-\frac{19}2\right)x^2+\left(\left(-\frac{19}2\right)^2-4\times\left(-\frac3{16}\right)\right)x-3^2\\&=x^3-19x^2+91x-9.\end{align}
4. Does it have a rational root which is a perfect square in $\mathbb Q$? Yes: $9(=3^2)$ is such a root.
5. [Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic#Third_definition) $q(x)=\left(x^2+3x+\beta\right)\left(x^2-3x+\gamma\right)$, with$$\beta=\frac12\left(-\frac{19}2+3^2-\frac33\right)=-\frac34\text{ and }\gamma=\frac12\left(-\frac{19}2+3^2+\frac33\right)=\frac14.$$
6. Since $p(x)=q\left(x+\frac12\right)$, you get a decomposition for $p(x)$:$$p(x)=(x^2+4x+1)(x^2-2x-1).$$

Comment: Even if the rational root of the resolvent cubic isn't a square, you still get a quadratic factorization; you just have to accept square roots in it.  Try $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, and for an added twist $x^4+x^3+x^2-x+1$.

Comment: My answer was about factorizations in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

For all real $k$ we have:

$$x^2+2x^3-8x^2-6x-1=(x^2+x+k)^2-x^2-k^2-2kx^2-2kx-8x^2-6x-1=$$
$$=(x^2+x+k)^2-((2k+9)x^2+2(k+3)x+k^2+1).$$
Now, we'll choose a value of $k$ such that
$$(2k+9)x^2+2(k+3)x+k^2+1=(ax+b)^2.$$
Easy to see that $k=0$ is valid.

In the general we need to solve the following equation.
$$(k+3)^2-(2k+9)(k^2+1)=0.$$
Id est, $$x^2+2x^3-8x^2-6x-1=(x^2+x+k)^2-x^2-k^2-2kx^2-2kx-8x^2-6x-1=$$
$$=(x^2+x+k)^2-((2k+9)x^2+2(k+3)x+k^2+1)=$$
$$=(x^2+x)^2-(9x^2+6x+1)=(x^2+x)^2-(3x+1)^2=(x^2-2x-1)(x^2+4x+1).$$

Answer (score 0):

Just working through the hint in the accepted answer, and verified with the Wolfram result in the second answer. Just for me, and maybe a check/guide for someone else:

> !$x^4+2x^3+x^2−9x^2−6x−1 \\
> (x^2+x)^2  - (3x+1)^2 \\
> \\
> ((x^2+x) + (3x+1)) ((x^2+x)  - (3x+1)) \\
> (x^2+4x+1) (x^2-2x-1) \\
> \\
> \text{quadratic formula for } (x^2+4x+1)\\
> -4/2\pm\sqrt{16-4}/2 \\
> -2 \pm\sqrt3 \\
> \\
> \text{quadratic formula for } (x^2-2x-1) \\
> --2/2\pm\sqrt{4-4(-1)}/2 \\
> 1\pm\sqrt{4+4}/2 \\
> 1\pm\sqrt2 \\
> \\
> \text{factored form }\\
> (x+2+\sqrt3)(x+2-\sqrt3)(x-1+\sqrt2)(x-1-\sqrt2)\\
> $